# how to construct a correct app.yaml for app engine standard environment for a Django app

Tags: django-rest-framework, google-app-engine-python, app.yaml

I am deploying a Python `rest_framework` application to app engine but my `app.yaml` fails with the error msg `(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create manifest file.`

I have tried to modify the `app.yaml` file. I have tried to deploy the app by declaring the python version as `python27` I succeeded to deploy it. However, other errors arise due to the fact that my `virtualenv` on my local machine is set to `python37`.

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 workshop.wsgi
instance_class: F2

beta_settings:
cloud_sql_instances: neverland:europe-west3:neverlandsql2

env_variables:
  SECRET_KEY: "*****************************************"
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "workshop.settings.settings"
  DEBUG: "True"


handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

I expect `app.yaml` to function even if the deployment environment is `python37`.

Comment: If you navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds, do you see any failed builds for your project? If so, can you share the contents of the logs?

Comment: I see no build fails because the app fails to deploy.

Comment: Can you share the deploy command you used, and the entire result of running it with the `--verbosity=debug` flag added?

Answer (score 0):

After more researching and contact google. It seems my project structure could be improved furthermore I was informed by Google that python 3.7 mentioned in my app.yaml is experimental at the moment and any other python can be used.

> What is the value of the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON variable at the moment of attempted deployment? Support for version 3.7 is experimental at present see answer below:-
>
> This error is related to the Python version used by the SDK: currently gcloud 
>    requires Python version 2.7.x and there is experimental support for 3.4 and up. 
>    You can check this by running the gcloud topic startup command on the CLI. 
>    Experimental support is what it says, so in this case you cannot deploy your app 
>    with CLOUDSDK_PYTHON set to python37. Things should progress towards full 
>    support; meanwhile, we should exercise patience.
>
> This situation should not prevent you from using whatever Python version you need 
>    for your project, and your app itself.